# PWABuilder - Android Store Package issue

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json, pwabuilder

This issue is not related to pwabuilder -> Building Android PWA APP but sort some issue after it is built.

OK here is the working fine example.

1. I install app (**Add to home screen**) from chrome
2. Share target works fine
3. Also I can view app in Fullscreen

Now I go to [PWA Builder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/) for build my android app to publish on play store

1. I build app for android
2. I install app in my android device
3. Share target not working!
4. I can not view app in full screen (I want to get rid of Address bar)

Is there a way around to fix this behaviour?

**NOTE** From [PWA Builder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/) I build app for Microsoft Store and in my initial testing I found that it is working fine as I want it to be. (2 & 3 points above from **Add to home screen** working fine)

Any help for android issue will be much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ok finally I got this today.

This [post](https://pwa-for-wp.com/docs/article/my-apk-is-showing-top-bar/) says how to overcome this.

**Solve:** *Remove the URL bar Trusted Web Activities(PWA APK) require an association between the Android application and the website to be established to remove the URL bar.*

Follow the below steps to remove bar:

1. Go APK zip make sure there is assetlinks.json [If not available regenerate again]
2. Add the asset link on /.well-known/assetlinks.json path and serve it from your domain.
3. Check your https:// YOUR_HOST/.well-known/assetlinks.json is exited or not exited
4. If not available above link, then create a .well-known folder in the root and upload assetlinks.json file from zip in a .well-known folder, Make sure this link properly renders the content
5. Now you are ready, Clear your browser and app data from mobile

For more information or verify assetlinks.json (content below) values for this [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator).

```
[{
"relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
"target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "android package id",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["Upload key certificate -> SHA-256 certificate fingerprint"]
}
}]
```

[image]

After all these steps my Android App is now not showing Top Address Bar.

Comment: And what about share_target how did you solved share target issue ?

Comment: @AnuragVohra It should be in your "Manifest" file, there should be value for "share_target" declared (JSON or XML)

Comment: I have that entry in my PWA,  and it works if user install apps without play store. Since after published to play store this share target is no more working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok did you set up .wellknown as per my answer above. And also the site must be in https

Comment: All done, my app is already published to app store

Comment: PWAbuilder.com also has instructions on how to remove the address bar for Android  https://docs.pwabuilder.com/#/builder/android?id=_3-update-your-asset-links-file-for-production